# SAML AuthnRequest are sent every 10 minutes to the IdP

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am struggling to understand why in certain cases a web application repeatedly sends AuthnRequest requests to the IdP. Is this behaviour configurable on the application side or on the IdP side? Does Spring SAML application send the AuthNRequest only once when logging in or can it send it also later? I checked the spring-security-saml source code and the method 'sendAuthenticationRequest' is executed only during SSO initialization in org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint#initializeSSO so I am confused.

Here is some background: application sends keep-alive requests every 10 minutes, each of those requests triggers sending AuthNRequest:

```
2020-10-19 12:01:50,335  INFO SAMLDefaultLogger.java:129 - log - AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;10.3.139.13;app1;https://sts.windows.net/acb2b37b-5da0-189b-9b83-0014b27a7c18/;;;
2020-10-19 12:11:50,333  INFO SAMLDefaultLogger.java:129 - log - AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;10.3.139.13;app1;https://sts.windows.net/acb2b37b-5da0-189b-9b83-0014b27a7c18/;;;
2020-10-19 12:21:50,361  INFO SAMLDefaultLogger.java:129 - log - AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;10.3.139.13;app1;https://sts.windows.net/acb2b37b-5da0-189b-9b83-0014b27a7c18/;;;
```

Answer (score 0):

How long is the session between the SP and the browser? If the SP session has expired it would trigger an authentication request.

Is the application configured to require authentication even if an IDP session exists?
E.g saml.sso.profile-options.force-authn=true.

Comment: Hi Steve, the HTTP session timeout defined in web.xml is 120 minutes, forceAuthN is set to false.